# Assembly for DBDataContext, I am so new

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005

I peek into my classmate's computer program and I see this:

```
DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();
```

I try the same but my program reports that There is no `DBDataContext`, what assembly is it I need to reference now?

Comment: I recently wrote a class named `Foo`. Do you also expect the assembly exposing that class to be available on your machine?

Comment: Your best chance is to hope for your classmate is also using SO

Comment: Cheater, cheater, pumpkin eater.

Comment: Go thru http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs (MVC3)  or http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4 ( MVC 4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are your classmate is using LINQ to SQL or something similar, and `DBDataContext` is a class in her solution, created by the LINQ to SQL designer.

Of course, the best way to learn from your classmate's code isn't to just "peek" into it - it's to ask them about it. In the process of them explaining and you listening and asking questions, you're both likely to learn.